# referencing latex table in quarto

Tags: r, reference, latex, quarto

I have the following table in my quarto document and I would like to reference it automatically in my text.

Quarto understands that this is my second table and is able to name it Table 2 in the caption but I can't find a way to reference this table automatically in my text.

I have this line in my YAML to make the table work.

````
---
format: pdf
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multirow} 
---


```{=latex}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Summary of the different variabilities when comparing marks from same or different tools and zones}
\label{Variabilities}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll|cc|}
\cline{3-4}
                                                     &                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tool}}                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                                     &                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textit{Same}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textit{Different}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Zone}}} & \textit{Same}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}             & B                                       \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                               & \textit{Different} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B}             & B                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```
````

If anyone knows how to give this table a label that I can call in the text for referencing.

**HERE IS THE ANSWER TO THIS**

Two more lines have to be introduced to the YAML in order to use the package cleveref

```
---
format: pdf
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
---
```

The way the table is written does not change.
To reference the table in the text as "Table X", you have to write

`\ref{Variabilities}`

(because I have `\label{Variabilities}` in my table).

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your help

Comment: Did you already try `\ref{Variabilities}`

Comment: I just tried, it almost worked, It got it referenced as "2" and not as "Table 2"

Comment: To automatically add the word table, use the `cleveref` package and use `\cref{...}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\cref{Variabilities}` from the `cleveref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{Summary of the different variabilities when comparing marks from same or different tools and zones}
\label{Variabilities}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll|cc|}
\cline{3-4}
 &                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tool}}                                           \\ \cline{3-4} 
 &                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textit{Same}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textit{Different}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Zone}}} & \textit{Same}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{W}             & B                                       \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                               & \textit{Different} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B}             & B                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\cref{Variabilities}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem, this is great!

Comment: @vengefulsealion You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Two more lines have to be introduced to the YAML in order to use the package cleveref

```
---
format: pdf
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
---
```

The way the table is written does not change. To reference the table in the text as "Table X", you have to write

\ref{Variabilities}

(because I have \label{Variabilities} in my table).

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your help